# numpy ndarray buffer is too small for requested array

Tags: python, numpy, shared-memory, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to setup a shared memory buffer using a structured numpy array.

I have no problems if I only use (datetime's, int's, float's) or (string's, int's, float's). I am however running into a 'TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array' error if I try and use (string's, datetime's, int's, float's).

Scratching my head about why this isn't working.  Any help is appreciated.

**This works:**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

N_list_size = 100_000

a = [
     (datetime.now(), 
      np.uint64(1234), 
      np.float64("123.4"))
] * N_list_size

np_array = np.ndarray(shape=(N_list_size,),
                      buffer=np.array(a),
                      dtype=[
                              ('a', np.datetime64),
                              ('b', np.uint64),
                              ('c', np.float64),
                      ])

shape, dtype = np_array.shape, np_array.dtype
print(f"np_array's size = {np_array.nbytes / 1e6}MB")
print(f"np_array's dtype = {dtype}")
```

**This also works:**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

N_list_size = 100_000

a = [
     ("d50ec984-77a8-460a-b958-66f114b0de9b", 
      np.uint64(1234), 
      np.float64("123.4"))
] * N_list_size

np_array = np.ndarray(shape=(N_list_size,),
                      buffer=np.array(a),
                      dtype=[
                              ('a', np.str_, 36),
                              ('b', np.uint64),
                              ('c', np.float64),
                      ])

shape, dtype = np_array.shape, np_array.dtype
print(f"np_array's size = {np_array.nbytes / 1e6}MB")
print(f"np_array's dtype = {dtype}")
```

**This does NOT work:**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

N_list_size = 100_000

a = [
     ("d50ec984-77a8-460a-b958-66f114b0de9b", 
      datetime.now(),
      np.uint64(1234), 
      np.float64("123.4"))
] * N_list_size

np_array = np.ndarray(shape=(N_list_size,),
                      buffer=np.array(a),
                      dtype=[
                              ('a', np.str_, 36),
                              ('b', np.datetime64),
                              ('c', np.uint64),
                              ('d', np.float64),
                      ])

shape, dtype = np_array.shape, np_array.dtype
print(f"np_array's size = {np_array.nbytes / 1e6}MB")
print(f"np_array's dtype = {dtype}")
```

and fails with:

```
TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

**Why is using both a datetime and string together causing an issue here?**

How to fix this?

Comment: Not sure, but specifying the units for datetime seems to work: ```np_array = np.array(a, dtype=[('a', 'U36'), ('b', 'datetime64[m]'), ('c', np.uint64), ('d', np.float64)])```

Comment: You could also use the string representation of the date instead of using pythons date-time. Just do ```str(datetime.now())``` instead of ```datetime.now()```. Working with date-times as strings is usually more convenient imo

Comment: `datetune.now()` creates a Python datatime object.  That is not the same thing as a `np.datetime64` element.

Comment: When I try to display the first `np_array` (for a small number of elements), I get a ValueError, regarding the display of the generic `datetime64`.  Even when I correct that I still get relatively meaningless display of values.

Comment: `np.array(a)` creates an object dtype array.  That is, it contains pointers to objects else where in memory.  You can't meaningfully view those pointers as `float64`, `int` etc.  Test this is much small arrays, ones which you can examine in detail.  Simply checking shape and dtype is not enough!

Comment: In the 2nd case, `np.array(a)` makes a 'U36' dtype array, 432 bytes per "row".  That's more than the bytes required by that compound dtype (320), so it does not raise an error.  But the `view` is still not valid.

Comment: `np.ndarray` is a low level constructor that requires advanced knowledge to use right.  I rarelly have used it, nor debugged other uses often.  And make sure you understand the `np.array(a)` construction before trying to create a `view` of it.  Structured views require a careful mapping between the original elements and the compound dtypes.

Comment: @Kevin using 'datetime64[m]' results in the same 'buffer is too small for requested array' error for me.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the good comments/info. In the spirit of getting things working I'm going with simply using a fixed-length string representation of the datetime (e.g.  datetime.isoformat())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the spirit of getting things working, and based on @Kevin's comment,  the following simple fixed-length string representation of the datetime (e.g. datetime.isoformat()) certainly works:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

N_list_size = 100_000

a = [
     ("d50ec984-77a8-460a-b958-66f114b0de9b", 
      datetime.now().isoformat(),
      np.uint64(1234), 
      np.float64("123.4"))
] * N_list_size

dtype=[
    ('a', 'U36'),
    ('b', 'U25'),
    ('c', np.uint64),
    ('d', np.float64),
]

np_array = np.ndarray(shape=(N_list_size,),
                      buffer=np.array(a,dtype=dtype),
                      dtype=dtype)

shape, dtype = np_array.shape, np_array.dtype
print(f"np_array's size = {np_array.nbytes / 1e6}MB")
print(f"np_array's dtype = {dtype}")
```

Output:

```
np_array's size = 28.4MB
np_array's dtype = [('a', '<U36'), ('b', '<U25'), ('c', '<u8'), ('d', '<f8')]
```

Comment: So it runs.  But do the values look reasonable?  Compare `np.array(a)[0]` with `np_array[0]`.  Do you see a `1234` in the later?  Better yet, look at the next element, [1].

Comment: @hpaulj the values will only be the same if you copy np.array(a,dtype=dtype) into np_array (e.g. np.copyto(np_array, np.array(a,dtype=dtype))). The important part for me was making sure I got the memory sizes correct so I can use a multiprocessing shared memory buffer with the np_array.

Comment: I missed the fact that you are now using the `dtype`to create the buffer: `np.array(a,dtype=dtype)`.  But if you do this, what's the point to using `ndarray` at all?  Also, now I think your `dtype` could include `datetime64[n]` without problem.  Your original problem(s) was because `np.array(a)` ended up `object` or `U32`, with bad buffer size (either too large or too small).

Comment: @hpaulj my main reason for using ndarray is essentially to get the memory sizing correct for a shared memory buffer, similar to what is being done here (https://mingze-gao.com/posts/python-shared-memory-in-multiprocessing/)

Comment: `np.zeros(N_list_size, dtype=dtype)` makes an array of the right size.